# Scrolling from section to section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website that has some sections, each of them is 100% height of window, but minimum of 800px

I want to make scrolling that will move the view from section to section in one scroll, but if the scroll is lower then 800 will act like usual scrolling until reach end or start of new section then scroll to it.

I tried to write myself a script, but it not working good enoght
Is there a good script or tutorial?

(This is what I tried to do so far... but without success...)

```
var prevScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var currentSection = getCurrentSection();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var newScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (newScroll > prevScroll){
        checkScrolling("down");
    } else {
        checkScrolling("up");
    }
    prevScroll = newScroll;
});


function checkScrolling(direction) {

    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = Math.max($(window).height(), 800);
    var currentPlace = $(currentSection).offset().top;

    if ( direction == "down" ) {
        if ( currentSection != ".blogs" ) {
            var nextPlace = $(currentSection).next().offset().top;
            if ( fromTop+windowHeight >= nextPlace ) {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: nextPlace}, 1000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    currentSection = getCurrentSection();
                }, 1001);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( currentSection != ".about" ) {
            var prevPlace = $(currentSection).prev().offset().top;
            if ( fromTop <= prevPlace+windowHeight ) {
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevPlace}, 1000);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    currentSection = getCurrentSection();
                }, 1001);
            }
        }
    }
}

function getCurrentSection() {
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = Math.max($(window).height(), 800);
    var s1 = $(".about").offset().top;
    var s2 = $(".works").offset().top;
    var s3 = $(".blogs").offset().top;

    if ( s1 <= fromTop && fromTop < s1+windowHeight ) {
        return ".about";
    } else if ( s2 <= fromTop && fromTop < s2+windowHeight ) {
        return ".works";
    } else if ( s3 <= fromTop && fromTop <= s3+windowHeight ) {
        return ".blogs";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i advise you to see scrollMagic

http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

Comment: This is for parallax, I don't see something that make scroll from section to section in one scroll...

Comment: You can't because scroll event ob document is called  each time the event is triggered. You can set a interval and boolean to tell your jquery to scroll or not (the only way with your code and scroll event).

Answer (score 0):

I develop a little jquery script to answer.
copy paste ans test with up and down touch.

```js
var prevScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var currentSection = getCurrentSection();


$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var newScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38: // up
         checkScrolling("up");
        break;

        case 40: // down
         checkScrolling("down");
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    prevScroll = newScroll;
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
;


function checkScrolling(direction) {

    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var currentSection = getCurrentSection();
    var windowHeight = Math.max($(window).height(), 800);
    var currentPlace = $(currentSection).offset().top;

    if ( direction == "down" ) {

         if( $(currentSection).next().length > 0){
                var nextPlace = $(currentSection).next().offset().top;
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: nextPlace}, 1000);
                $(currentSection).removeClass("current").
                next().addClass('current');
        }

    } else {
        if( $(currentSection).prev().length > 0){
                var prevPlace = $(currentSection).prev().offset().top;
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: prevPlace}, 1000);
                $(currentSection).removeClass("current").
                prev().addClass('current');
        }
    }
}

function getCurrentSection() {
    return  $(".current");
}
```

```css
body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
  }

  body section{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   max-height: 800px;
  }

  body section:nth-child(1){
   background: grey;
  }
  body section:nth-child(2){
   background: red;
  }
  body section:nth-child(3){
   background: yellow;
  }
  body section:nth-child(4){
   background: cyan;
  }

  body section[class=current]{
   border: 2px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test Scroll</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="current">
 </section>
 <section>
 </section>
 <section>
 </section>
 <section>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working, but I need script that will work with scrolling not with pressing up and down...